# Channel name in EventSource

Tags: c#, events, trace, system.diagnostics, etw

I have an application writing some ETW events. The event provider is created with a particular name like:

```
[EventSource(Name = "Test-SourceLogger")]
public class EventSourceLogger : EventSource
```

I then have various events inside this log to which some data is logged. Also, the logs are written via the trace above which a custom trace listener is created. This listener then writes the events.

Now, I want to see these events in the event viewer and I'm not able to find them. Basically, none of the left pane options in the viewer show the logs. I searched and it seems we somewhere have to specify the channel in the instrumentation manifest while registering the provider. I'm using .NET 4.5 framework and hence I need not explicitly register the provider.

- Is specifying channel name necessary?
- How can I view my logs in the
  event viewer in case I don't have it? Isn't there any default channel
  where they get pushed?
- I tried viewing the events via perfview, I
  see the events for my application. On dumping the event's xml, I see
  the channel attribute is set to 0. How can I see the name
  corresponding to each channel number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the Channel property of the Event attribute like this:

```
[EventSource(Name = "Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog")]
public sealed class MinimalEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static MinimalEventSource Log = new MinimalEventSource();
    [Event(601, Channel = EventChannel.Admin,  Message = "Unhandled exception occurred. Details: {0}", Keywords = EventKeywords.None, Level = EventLevel.Critical)]
    private void UnhandledException(string exceptionMsg)
    {
        this.IsEnabled().Dump();
        this.WriteEvent(601, exceptionMsg);
    }
}
```

Channel 0 means None, see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventchannel?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> Admin       16      The administrator log channel.
>   Analytic    18      The analytic channel.
>   Debug       19      The debug channel.
>   None         0      No channel specified.
>   Operational 17    The operational channel.

But, AFAIK, you still need to register your event source, see [this doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-samples/blob/master/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing/EventSource/docs/EventSource.md#etw-channel-support)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked the nuget packet 1.1.28 which provides the channel support and that does via Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing. While my application is using System.Diagnostics.Tracing. Any way channel can be added via that? And without adding channel, the event will not be visible in the event viewer?

Comment: @user1915032 update solution to .net 4.6, here inbox class supports channel

Comment: As @magicandre1981 writes, you have to update to 4.6+ or use the Nuget classes

Comment: @PeterBons Can the channel names be changed? Like, if I want to have a channel name as Application, is it possible to do that from above?

Comment: Also, after adding the channel in the name above, the manifest file gets an entry like  Samples-EventSourceDemos-EventLog\Admin in the <channels> tag. But this is still not visible in the eventviewer. Any clue here?